# "for" command not working with space in (set) element

Tags: for-loop, command, set

I am working on a command script that will store the file size of a certain file as a variable so I can output it later in the script.

I can get it to work perfectly unless the (set) portion of the command points to a path with spaces in it.

This works:

```cmd
for /F %%A in ("%userprofile%\desktop\test2\test.jpg" ) do If %%~zA GTR 0 set INITIALSIZE=%%~zA 
msg "%username%" size of file: %INITIALSIZE%
```

It opens a dialog box with the file size of test.jpg.

If I change the name of the 'test2' folder to 'test 2' then it stops working. It never stores a value into INITIALSIZE. This is needed because the actual path the final script will point to is in Program Files.

These do not work:

```cmd
for /F %%A in ("%userprofile%\desktop\test 2\test.jpg" ) do If %%~zA GTR 0 set INITIALSIZE=%%~zA 
msg "%username%" size of file: %INITIALSIZE% 

for /F %%A in (""%userprofile%\desktop\test 2\test.jpg"" ) do If %%~zA GTR 0 set INITIALSIZE=%%~zA 
msg "%username%" size of file: %INITIALSIZE% 

for /F %%A in ("%userprofile%\desktop\"test 2"\test.jpg" ) do If %%~zA GTR 0 set INITIALSIZE=%%~zA 
msg "%username%" size of file: %INITIALSIZE% 

for /F %%A in ("'%userprofile%\desktop\test 2\test.jpg'" ) do If %%~zA GTR 0 set INITIALSIZE=%%~zA 
msg "%username%" size of file: %INITIALSIZE%
```

Any ideas about what syntax needs to be used here? Forgive my ignorance I am a Newb.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Here an example how to do that

```
@echo off
set file1="d:\new folder\test.jpg"
call :getfilesize %file1% size
echo %size%
goto :eof

:getfilesize %a
set size=%~z1
goto :eof
```